# Вопрос по пунктуации

Tags: пунктуация

Добрый день! Мы с коллегами - инженеры, сейчас оформляем один чертёж и заспорили о том, как надо проставить запятые в двух конкретных предложениях. Я пока намеренно написал их без пунктуации. Вот они:

1) На марках в местах отмеченных знаками N и NN выбить номер точки ориентировки клиновых листов.
2) В местах отмеченных знаком M выбить номер марки.

У нас есть несколько вариантов. Помогите, пожалуйста, рассудить наш спор!

С уважением, Андрей

Answer (score 1):

1. *На марках в местах, отмеченных знаками N и NN, выбить номер точки ориентировки клиновых листов*.
2. *В местах, отмеченных знаком N, выбить номер марки.*

В обоих случаях мы имеем причастный оборот, находящийся внутри предложения. Посему ставим две запятые. Возможно, в первом примере у Вас могут возникнут сомнения насчёт  отсутствия запятой в словах "На марках в местах". Здесь она не нужна.

Comment: Верно,в обычной речи уточнение возможно,в чертежах чем проще надпись, тем лучше. И ещё - по невнимательности Вы во 2 примере " знаком M" поменяли на "знаком N", поправьте

Comment: Ага, у меня тоже возник вопрос "где именно?".

Comment: Нет-нет - там всё правильно. В первом предложении N и NN, а во втором - именно M. Но это в любом случае уже непринципиально. :))

Comment: Это не у Вас, у Tagirix

Answer (score 0):

Правильно:  На марках в местах, отмеченных знаками N и NN***,***  выбить номер точки ориентировки клиновых листов. 2) В местах, отмеченных знаком M ***,***выбить номер марки.
Запятые закрывают причастный оборот.

Comment: А почему не нужно ставить запятые в начале причастного оборота - после определяемого слова? Я всегда считал, что причастный оборот выделяется с обеих сторон, если определяющее слово стоит перед ним. То есть: На марках в местах, отмеченных знаками N и NN, выбить номер точки ориентировки клиновых листов. 2) В местах, отмеченных знаком M, выбить номер марки

Comment: Совершено верно. Причастный оборот выделяется с двух сторон запятыми. В чем проблема? У меня же выделено с двух сторон.

Comment: Нет, у Вас присутствует ошибка в первом предложении. Внимательно посмотрите =)

Comment: Действительно, опечатка. Даже не заметил.Все исправлено.

Answer (score 0):

Можно предложить еще один вариант:
1) На марках, в  отмеченных знаками N и NN местах, выбить номер точки ориентировки клиновых листов. 
2) В местах, отмеченных знаком M, выбить номер марки.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Начало предложения "На марках в местах..."  неудобно для прочтения. Здесь встречаются два неоднородных обстоятельства, одно из которых распространено причастным оборотом.

В предложенном варианте мы имеем только уточняющее обстоятельство.